# Почему не совпадает размер текста при задании через xml и код?

Tags: java, android, android-textview

Создал файл ресурсов res/value/dimens. В него добавил строку

`<dimen name="size">20dp</dimen>`

В макете создал два TextView. Для одного размер указал в макете

`android:textSize="20dp"`

Для другого размер указал в активити

```
float size;
size = this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.size);
textView.setTextSize(size);
```

Я надеялся получить две надписи одинакового размера. Но оказалось, что размер textView у которой размер указан в активности в 2 раза больше, чем у первой. Если я меняю строку строку в dimens на

`<dimen name="size">10dp</dimen>`

Тогда размеры одинаковы. Подскажите, в чём моя ошибка?

Вот мой макет целиком:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `setTextSize` ожидает размерность в `sp`, чтобы туда `dp` положить, надо вызвать с двумя параметрами `textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, size)`.
Но вообще рекомендую использовать для размера текста `sp` юниты - это позволит системе дополнительно регулировать размер исходя из настроек пользователя

Comment: Я поменял параметры как вы советовали. Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: После этого в ресурсах поменял строку android:textSize="20sp", и в макете размер указал 20sp. Поменял на textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size). Результат не поменялся.

Comment: Добавьте полную верстку обоих TextView пожалуйста

Comment: Добавил в вопрос вёрстку

Comment: `textView.setTextSize(20)` или `textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size)`. Метод `getDimension()` конвертирует указанное значение в зависимости от типа и конфигурации и выдаёт его в пикселях.

Comment: Сделал как вы посоветовали. Для первого TextView указал в макете размер 20px. Для второго прочёл данные из ресурса - 20px.  Но результат НЕ изменился. Первая TextView ровно в 2 раза меньше, чем вторая. Если меняю в макете размер на 40px тогда они одинаковые

Comment: Когда это я вам советовал указать всё в `px`? В ресурсах всё задайте в `sp`, а в коде как я написал.

Comment: С вашей помощью всё получилось. Оказывается всё довольно просто, но разобраться самому не удалось.